# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{ \cot^{-1} (\sqrt {x+1} -\sqrt x}{\sec^{-1} (\frac{2x+1}{x-1})^x}$

Tags: limits

I can simplify the numerator by converting into $\arctan$ And then rationalising inside the function which would give me $\tan^{-1} \infty =\frac{\pi}{2}$, but i don’t know how to deal with the denominator

Comment: Hint: $2^\infty$ is not an indeterminate form

Comment: @NinadMunshi where did you get $2^{\infty}$ from?

Comment: It's the limit of the argument to the arcsecant.

Comment: @EricTowers yeah that was my guess too, just wanted to confirm if limit can be applied in the argument directly

Comment: @Aditya : If $f$ is continuous in an open interval containing $g(c)$ (or at least containing $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} g(x)$), $$\lim_{x \rightarrow c} f( g(x)) = f\left( \lim_{x \rightarrow c} g(x) \right) $$ ... assuming $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} g(x)$ exists (otherwise, neither side of this equality has a value so use of an equality would be grammatically wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x+1} -\sqrt{x} = \sqrt x ( \sqrt{1+1/x} - 1 ) \approx \sqrt x(1+\frac{1}{2x} -1) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt x} \to 0 $$ So, the top is $\cot^{-1} (0) = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Also, $$\frac{2x+1}{x-1} \to 2$$ and when you raise $2$ to a huge power, you get $\infty$. So, the bottom is $\sec^{-1} (\infty)= \frac{\pi}{2}$

The limit then evaluates to $\frac{\pi/2}{\pi/2} =1 $.